# Homeomorphism groups on manifolds and topological properties

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-dimensional manifold let $H(M)$ denote the homeomorphism group of $M$.

If $n=2$ then $H(M)$ enjoys nice properties such as being an ANR, is locally contractible, separable. The dimension restriction for $n=2$ is superfluous for local contractibility.

However, is $H(M)$ locally compact and in general finite dimensional? Is it a Lie group in general?

In the non-compact case, consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $H(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is homotopy equivalent to $O(2)$; albeit this doesn't say much.

Comment: Do you mean the isometry group of a manifold with metric, instead of homeomorphism group? There are many many more homeos of $\mathbb R^2$ than $O(2)$.

Comment: @KevinCasto No. I fixed it. I meant deformation retract instead of equality. Sorry

Comment: If the manifold is infinite, the homeomorphism group is not locally compact, since every neighborhood of the identity contains a closed, noncompact subgroup.

Comment: And if the manifold is positive-dimensional, one can embed $\mathbf{R}^n$ as closed subgroup for all $n$ (even in every neigh. of identity) so the group is infinite-dimensional. Conversely if the manifold is discrete, the homeomorphism group (=symmetric group) is zero-dimensional.

Comment: @YCor Just to get the story straight; when you say "manifold is infinite" you mean the dimension, right?  In such a case, if the manifold is positive (finite) dimensional,  is it locally compact?

Comment: @SomePerson no: I mean when the number of points is infinite. That is, either there is a positive-dimensional component, or there are infinitely many components

Comment: Local contractibility (when equipped with the compact open topology) holds in all dimensions: This is due to Chernavsky.

Comment: Deciding if $Homeo(M)$ is an ANR is a well-known open problem (except as you say if $\dim(M)\le 2$). Separability of $Homeo(M)$ is immediate because it is a subspace of the space of continuous self-maps of $M$, which is is metrizable and second countable, and these two properties are inherited by subspaces.